# Bash file is running fine in windows for testng but it is not working in linux/mac

Tags: linux, macos, bash, selenium-webdriver, testng

My bash file is running fine in windows but it is not working in linux/mac. 
I have created a selenium project with testng and I want to create a bash file so I can run my project without IDE

I have searched but till not getting any solution for same

Error on terminal:-

```
>bash TestNg_RunMe.bat 
>Error: Could not find or load main class ..src.lib.selenium-java-2.46.0.jar
>TestNg_RunMe.bat: line 1: ./bin: Is a directory
```

Note:- I have use **bash** command also to run the command in linux and mac

Also lib and bin directory is present in right place(As it working fine in windows)

My bash file is :-

```
java -cp ./src/lib/*;./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Above bash is working perfect for windows
I have also tried with full absolute path 
I have also extract testng.jar and add it in bash file
but nothing work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paths are separated using `:` under Unix-like systems and not `;` as in Windows:

```
java -cp ./src/lib/*:./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

If you are using `bash` under Windows then changing to `:` should work everywhere.

The `;` character means *end of statement* to a Unix shell, so what you are attempting to exceute is:

```
java -cp ./src/lib/*
./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: @ShubhamJain assuming that solved your problem you should also accept the answer

Comment: @Ericrenouf - Done :)