# Run Java TestNG test from .Net

Tags: java, .net, testng

I have created a java project to run automated test cases for native app using appium and selenium.

Now our clients want to run that java project through .NET.

I have tried using ikvm.net but it says "Manifest doesn't contain a Main-class" because testNG class doesn't contain main class.

Can anybody suggest another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As testng is for java you can do something like this:-

You can create a bash file for testng which is execute testng for java

Refer:-

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120102/bash-file-is-running-fine-in-windows-for-testng-but-it-is-not-working-in-linux-m
```

Now you need to execute that bash from a C# code

```
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/how-can-i-run-a-terminal-command-bash-from-c-mono
```

Hope it will help you :)