# How to run the selenium code on linux using firefox without GUI?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, redhat, headless-browser

I had redhat Linux server command line but there is no GUI for that and I need to run selenium code on this server with firefox. As I am new to selenium so I am not sure whether it will work or not.

For achieving this I had install Firefox on my Redhat linux machine successfully but not able to trigger that as it is showing **no display found**.

Is there any other way to achieve this for headless browsing, where virtually a firefox will be opened and selenium code can be executed without GUI. Is it possible to do??

Comment: you would need to do xvfb settings for display to be found on some machine while running selenium tests on linux

Comment: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HtmlUnitDriver` of selenium to use headless browsing but it will not open firefox and may be not loading all content to it's cache as same as firefox

Refer Below:-

```
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver
```

Another thing you can use is Phantomjs with selenium Webdriver. This is most using pattern by industries for headless browsing

Refer below:-

```
http://www.guru99.com/selenium-with-htmlunit-driver-phantomjs.html
```

Yes you can trigger selenium file using command line

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_executing_tests.htm

[Bash file is running fine in windows for testng but it is not working in linux/mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120102/bash-file-is-running-fine-in-windows-for-testng-but-it-is-not-working-in-linux-m)

Now if still your firefox is not opening then it is basically issue of some setting with your OS with firefox

Refer that too :-

https://serverfault.com/questions/279036/open-terminal-via-ssh-run-firefox-display-not-found

May be you have problem with some permission in red hat

Hope it will help you :)